# resize blogger image widget according to screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I've the following code to display some images side by side in a blogger blog but I'm facing the display size issue

```
<style type="text/css">.nobrtable br { display: none }</style>
<div class="nobrtable">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><a href="URL" target="_blank" title="pic1">
<img height=200 width=120 src="IMAGE LINK" alt="pic name" style="border:none;"/></a></td>
<td><a href="URL" target="_blank" title="pic2">
<img height=200 width=120 src="IMAGE LINK" alt="pic name" style="border:none;"/></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The problem is that if I put more than 2 images in a row or not reduce the width of the images in the above code, the images won't fit on screen while using a small screen device like mobile devices. It works fine on computer browsers because there's enough space for the images to fit.

What I want to do here is that, I want to display more than 2 images in a row and on mobile devices, it should be auto arranged. What i meant is that, let's say I put 6 images in the above code, on mobile devices, I want to display two images in a row, the next two images under it and so on(like tiles). Right now when I use the above code and check the blog on mobile, I can see only the first image displayed properly and half of the second image. Third image is not visible at all. I want all the images to have same width and height and if the screen doesn't have enough space to display an image in the same row, it should be moved to the next line automatically. How can I do this?

Comment: Use **Media Query** `@media` rules for your mobile screen.

Comment: Thanks Dan but can you show me how and where exactly to use it? I don't have much idea about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the height:width ratio you are using reflects that of the original image, and thus only specifying width. The image will be 100% of its parent, the `a` element. You can control it further by specifying the width, position, etc. of the `nobrtable` element.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .nobrtable a   { display: block; float: left; width:50%; max-width:120px; }
  .nobrtable img { border:solid 1px black; float:left; width: 100%; }
</style>
<div class="nobrtable">
  <a href="URL" target="_blank" title="pic1">
    <img src="IMAGE LINK" alt="pic name" />
  </a>
  <a href="URL" target="_blank" title="pic2">
    <img src="IMAGE LINK" alt="pic name" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi inarilo, it worked great. Thanks a lot. Btw, if you can help, I've one more doubt.  How can I add a title to every pic, preferably at the bottom of every image(above every image, not outside). Right now, the title appears only when hovering the mouse, that too only  on desktop browser, not on mobile

Comment: @MarkLopez add `position:relative` to the `a` style and this line .`.nobrtable span { position: absolute; width: 100%; text-align:center; display:block; padding: 5px 10px; bottom: 0; font: bold 20px Verdana; }`. Add each `span` with the title below each `img` tag. You can also use `h1` etc. instead but it appears to have its own padding defined, so I picked `span` instead. btw just realised I added a border to the image :) and forgot to remove it.

Comment: Thanks inarilo. I'll check